# Running Java programs

Tags: java

I'm running into Main method not found in class Raytracer, please define the main method as:   public static void main(String[] args).

But when I do that, I get a bunch of non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context (and no matter how much statics I append, I'm still stuck unable to run the program).

What should I do?

Comment: Post the code its difficult to point out the mistake

Comment: you can include some relevant code in your question

Comment: Where is your code? Adding your code to your question improve the quality of question and increase the possibility of getting an answer fast.

Comment: Don't just randomly add "static" all over the place. Learn about the difference between static and instance members, *think*, and fix your code.

Comment: can you show your class?

Comment: Generally, I would post my code up, but in this case, it's for a project in my class and pushing a potential solution to the internet would be bad. Sorry about the bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the constructor for your Main class, and start your code from there. When your static main method is running, your Main class has not been instantiated yet, so you can only reference static members at that point.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Main();
    }

    Main() {
        //do stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: @dcheng feel free to select my answer as the right one, then :)